# Spring + QueryDsl + Mockito: How to write a unit test case for a simple function

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, mockito, querydsl

I have the following function in my service.

```
public boolean checkNameUnique(String name) {
    QEntity qEntity = QEntity.entity;
    BooleanExpression nameUniquePredicate = qEntity.name.eq(name);
    long count = entityReadRepository.count(nameUniquePredicate);
    return count == 0;
}
```

It just checks if the name already exists in db. That needs to be unique, so it returns true if does not already exist and false if it does.

Now how do I write a mockito unit test case for this? I am new to Mockito and writing unit test cases, hence the question.

My reading on Mockito has lead me to write something on the lines of

```
when(entityReadRepository.count(nameUniquePredicate)).thenReturn(1);
```

and then call the function to be tested. But that doesn't make any sense.

`Entity` is Hibernate entity which corresponds to a table in the DB
`entityReadRepository` extends `JpaRepository` and `QueryDslPredicateExecutor`. `QEntity` is the `Q` object generated by `QueryDsl`'s plugin.

Comment: I am thinking if I can mock the insertion of a object into the repo and then the checkNameUnique automatically picks up that so and so object is present.

Comment: "But that doesn't make any sense" why do you say that? your mocking code looks correct to me. if this is a unit test, you should not be testing your persistence layer, you should not have to test if your db layer is doing what it is supposed to do.

Comment: I say that because I am just over-writing the statement to return 1. Is that a valid way of testing that code? or is it that this function is so simple and db dependent that a mockito unit test case does not make sense here?

Comment: Also, I was looking for some solution where I can say like insert a mock object in the mock repo and then when I call the function it should search the mock repo and give the answer? Is that even possible in mockito?

Comment: and after more reading about it, I am seeing people use entity manager and try that. but that wont work for me. I am not using any entity manager as such. its all abstracted away into the querydsl and jparepository extensions

Comment: IMO, i think a mock repo is an unnecessary overhead for a simple unit test like this. I would use a mock repo if you are writing an integration test that tests several services across an application.

Comment: ok cool. that makes sense. the overhead

Answer (score 0):

A unit test would normally mock out any external dependencies, in your case entityReadRepository. If you want to do actual db call it would be classed as integration test. 
Your method should return two different values depending on the entityReadRepository response and this is what you would stub in order to unit test it. You were on a good path trying:

```
when(entityReadRepository.count(any(BooleanExpression.class))).thenReturn(1l);
```

The problem you have is that you have a lot of static calls and objects in your method and that can't be handled gracefully. One option is to use tools like Powermockito where you can mock behaviour of static methods. If you prefer to stick with mockito you could extract static piece of code to a separate method and create a spy of your class under test:

```
package com.slavpilus;

    import org.junit.Assert;
    import org.junit.Before;
    import org.junit.Test;
    import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
    import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
    import org.mockito.Mock;
    import org.mockito.Spy;
    import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

    import static org.mockito.Matchers.any;
    import static org.mockito.Mockito.doReturn;
    import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;


    @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
    public class TPresenterTest {

        @InjectMocks
        @Spy
        private ClassUnderTest target = new ClassUnderTest();

        @Before
        public void setUp() {
            doReturn(null).when(target).getUniqueNamePredicate();
        }

        @Mock
        private YourRepositoryDependency entityReadRepository;

        @Test
        public void checkNameUniqueShouldBeTrueIfNameNotInDatabase() {
            when(entityReadRepository.count(any())).thenReturn(0l);

            boolean isUnique = target.checkNameUnique("anyName");

            Assert.assertTrue(isUnique);
        }

        @Test
        public void checkNameUniqueShouldBeFalseIfNameFoundInDatabase() {
            when(entityReadRepository.count(any())).thenReturn(1l);

            boolean isUnique = target.checkNameUnique("anyName");

            Assert.assertFalse(isUnique);
        }
    }
```

and your production code would look something like that:

```
   public boolean checkNameUnique(String name) {
        BooleanExpression nameUniquePredicate = getUniqueNamePredicate();

        long count = entityReadRepository.count(nameUniquePredicate);
        return count == 0;
    }

    protected BooleanExpression getUniqueNamePredicate() {
        QEntity qEntity = QEntity.entity;
        return qEntity.name.eq(name);
    }
```

This approach however leaves you with some code untested as `getUniqueNamePredicate` method is skipped entirely during the test execution.